# Counting instances in dataframe that match to another instance

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6, pandas-groupby

So, I am working with over 100 attributes. Clearly cannot be using this

```
df['column_name'] >= 1 & df['column_name'] <= 1
```

Say my dataframe looks like this-

```
A B C D E F G H I
1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

I wish to find #instances with value 1 for labels C and I . Answer here is two( 2nd and 3rd row). I am working with a lot of attributes certainly cannot hardcode them. How can I be finding the frequency?
Consider I have access to the list of class labels I wish to work with i.e. [C,I]

Comment: Can you provide some more context? What’s in your DataFrame? I’m surprised to hear of a DataFrame with hundreds of columns.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want [`DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df[['C','I']].eq(1).all(axis=1).sum()
#2
```

---

We can also use:

```
df[['C','I']].astype(bool).all(axis=1).sum()
```

Comment: sorry. i am pretty new here. Accepted your answer! TYSM once again.!

Comment: Thank you! There is a tick below the number of votes of my answer, click to accept the answer :)